# Verifying if the elements of a vector are the same on an undefined range?

Tags: c++

For example, I have the number 22333333255545. I want to remove that sequences of 3 and 5. After that, the number is 22245, so the sequence of 2 should be erased and so on, until there is no sequence of 3 or more equal numbers. I know just for the case when only 3 elements are equal, I don't know for an unknown number.

What I have tried(every digit of the number is stored in the vector v,  vsize is the initial size of it):

```
for (long long i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; ++i) {
    if (v[i] == v[i+1] && v[i+1] == v[i+2]) {
        v.erase(v.begin() + i, v.begin() + i + 3);
    }
    vsize--;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Find the only non repeated number?

Comment: There is a function in the `<algorithm>` library that can be used to find ranges of equal elements. [`std::equal_range`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/equal_range/)

Comment: @NathanOliver, this is what I am trying to do: evaluate the vector, remove the repeating number, evaluate it again, remove the repeating number again and so on until there is no repeating number.

Comment: @lcs, can you, please, explain how to use the function on the example number that I have written? I didn't understand from the link that you have given.

Comment: Should 22233324 reduce to 24 or 4? (22233324 -> 33324 -> 24, or 22233324 -> 22224 -> 4?)

Comment: 22233324 -> 24, first the string has to be evaluated and numbers repeating deleted, then re-evaluated and that numbers deleted and so on.

Comment: @user7395692 `for (long long i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; ++i) { if (v[i] == v[i+1]`  - -This is clearly wrong, as `i+1` is out of bounds of the vector on the last iteration of the loop.  You can see this if `v.size() == 1`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, so what can I do?

Comment: In your sample, why did you start by looking at `3`?  The first set of repeating values is `2` (the first two characters).  Also, given your description, you should wind up with "245", not "24" if the input is "22333333255545".  Here is the sequence of steps:  22333333255545 (removing the leadiing "2") -> 333333255545 (Removing the "3") -> 255545 (Removing the 3 repeating "5") -> 245.  All unique.

Comment: I want to remove just sequences of 3 or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy enough if you create come simple steps:

1. Keep a reference to a start of a sequence.
2. Keep moving forward until you dont have that sequence anymore.
3. If when you end the sequence, your sequence references are more than the distance apart, delete the sequence.
4. Reset your start and end sequence pointers by rolling back to the start of the last sequence.
5. Keep going until you reach the end of the vector.

Here is some Psuedo Code:

```
    int maxSeq = n;
    int startSeq = 0, endSeq = 0;

    while (startSeq and endSeq < vector.size()) {
        if (vector[++endSeq] != vector[startSeq]) {
            // our sequence has ended.
            if (endSeq - startSeq > maxSeq) {
                // our sequence is long
                vector.erase( from startSeq to endSeq)
                reset startSeq and endSeq by rolling back to the start of the last sequence.
       }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain better, please? I'm a beginner in C++.

Comment: @user7395692 I have provided some psuedo code, but this is clearly homework, so you need to be able to handle this yourself

Comment: One more question, by "reset startSeq and endSeq by rolling back to the start of the last sequence." you mean startSeq = 0 and endSeq = 0?

Comment: And what is n? The size of the vector?

Comment: @user7395692 No i dont mean that, i mean go back to the start of the last sequence. And n is whatever you want it to be. This is psuedo code, you need to implement something and debug it, its the only way you will learn.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not well specified, as in the following sequence `222333333255545`, it depends on the order you proceed you'll get different results... if you begin geting `3` chars, you'll get to `222255545`, then you try with `2` and get `55545` and finally you try with `5` to get `45`.  This is different if you first try with `2` to get `333333255545`, then you try with `3` to get `255545` and finally with `5` to get `245`, which is different than the first time.

## Edit after first comment.

In case you want to begin on the left (in a greedy approach), where you ask to begin on the left, you have no alternative, but find a sequence of three or more similar digits, and then begin again (on the far left side) as you can miss some data if you continue with your approach.  Your approach is a multipass where you try to find as much similar characters as you can, in each pass:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string input = "2233333324455545";
const int N = 3;

int main()
{
    cout << input << endl;
    bool finished;
    int pass = 0;
    do {
            finished = true;
            auto i = input.begin();
            while (i + N < input.end()) {
                    auto j = i + 1;
                    while (j < input.end()) {
                            if (*i != *j) break;
                            j++;
                    }
                    if (j >= i + N) {
                            input.erase(i, j);
                            finished = false;
                    } else {
                            i++;
                    }
            }
            cout << input << " after pass #" << ++pass << endl;
    } while (!finished);
} /* main */
```

Which executes to:

```
$ greedy 
2233333324455545
2224445 after pass #1
5 after pass #2
5 after pass #3
```

Comment: I want the program to work like this: find the first sequence, delete it. Re-evaluate the number, find the first sequence, delete it and so on.